# Label.text Error! - Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type, mobile-development

I am new to iOS development and I found an error that I can not get past. I have read a lot online and on Stackoverflow but I don't understand why this error keeps coming up.

Upon testing and doing breakpoints I think I was able to get the data needed[image] problem is when I display it on screen wit uilabel.

```
import UIKit

class ArtistViewController: UIViewController, artistViewModelDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var artwork: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumName: UILabel!

    func loadArtistViewModel(data: ArtistViewModel) {
        guard let artistData = data as? ArtistViewModel else {}

        artistName.text = artistData.artistName //Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me on this one, Thank you so much!

**EDIT**

`ViewController` where the instance of `ArtistViewController` gets called

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

protocol artistViewModelDelegate {
    func loadArtistViewModel(data: ArtistViewModel)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, artistSearchDelegate {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var data: [ArtistItem] = []
    var delegate: artistViewModelDelegate?
    var artistViewModel: ArtistViewModel?
    var params = [API_CONSTANTS.URL_TYPES.PARAMETERS.TERM: "Maroon 5",API_CONSTANTS.URL_TYPES.PARAMETERS.COUNTRY: API_CONSTANTS.AU, API_CONSTANTS.URL_TYPES.PARAMETERS.MEDIA: API_CONSTANTS.URL_TYPES.PARAMETERS.MUSIC]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = ArtistViewController()
        getItunesData()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "artistCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "artistCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "artistCell", for: indexPath) as! artistCell

        cell.artistName.text = data[indexPath.row].artistName
        cell.albumName.text = data[indexPath.row].albumName
        cell.genre.text = data[indexPath.row].genre
        cell.trackPrice.text = "$\(String(data[indexPath.row].trackPrice))"
        cell.albumArtwork.load(url: data[indexPath.row].artwork)

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        return cell
    }
    //Mark: To Artist ViewController
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        artistViewModel = ArtistViewModel(artist: data[indexPath.row])
        let artistViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArtistViewController") as! ArtistViewController

        delegate?.loadArtistViewModel(data: artistViewModel!)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(artistViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func getItunesData(){
        Alamofire.request(API_CONSTANTS.URL_TYPES.URL, method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON
            { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let json = JSON(response.result.value)
                self.data = ArtistModel(json: json).artistItems
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
            }
        }
    }
    func didTapSearch(artist: String) {
        params = [API_CONSTANTS.URL_TYPES.PARAMETERS.TERM:"\(artist)"]
        getItunesData()
    }
    @IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let popupSearchVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupSearchView") as! PopupViewController
        popupSearchVC.delegate = self
        present(popupSearchVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: `artistName` is nil. Question is: Why? Did you connect the IBOutlet correctly? Did you load the Cell according to its Storyboard or custom Xib ie: how did you registered the cell?

Comment: When I do print I get the value of `artistName` I get the value, you can also see that on my breakpoint. Everything works fine but to this point.

Comment: I meant the `UILabel` var named `artistName`, not the `String` property of the `ArtistViewModel` instance named also `artistName` which is what's in the screenshot.

Comment: I believe the problem is not from the `UILabel`, I've tried `artistName.text = "test"` it works, I think the unwrapping the from `artistData.artistName` to `artistName.text` is the issue which I'm confused.

Comment: The screenshot displays only the contents of `artistData`, you have to look at `artistName` in `self`. And how/where is the instance of `ArtistViewController` created? if it's created with `let vc = ArtistViewController()` then the error is obvious.

Comment: Where did you test it? Just there? Could you do two lines, one above the other and check which one crashes?

Comment: Here we go. As I said `ArtistViewController()` is wrong. It's a brand new instance without connected outlets. You need the real reference to the storyboard instance with segue or instantiation.

Comment: @Vadian I've assigned `ArtistViewController()` to a delegate, is it a good practice?

Comment: No, it's a *no-go practice*. It's the error reason. Please re-read my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the protocol. You set `delegate` to an instance which is not the instance in the storyboard.

But with the given code you don't need the protocol at all.

Delete

```
protocol artistViewModelDelegate {
   func loadArtistViewModel(data: ArtistViewModel)
}
```

...

```
var delegate: artistViewModelDelegate?
```

...

```
self.delegate = ArtistViewController()
```

and the protocol conformance, then replace

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    artistViewModel = ArtistViewModel(artist: data[indexPath.row])
    let artistViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArtistViewController") as! ArtistViewController

    delegate?.loadArtistViewModel(data: artistViewModel!)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(artistViewController, animated: true)
}
```

with

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let artistViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArtistViewController") as! ArtistViewController

    artistViewController.artistViewModel = ArtistViewModel(artist: data[indexPath.row])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(artistViewController, animated: true)
}
```

---

And in `ArtistViewController` you have to use a temporary variable for the model because the outlets are not connected (yet) right after instantiation.

Replace the code in the question with

```
import UIKit

class ArtistViewController: UIViewController, artistViewModelDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var artwork: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumName: UILabel!

    var artistViewModel : ArtistViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        artistName.text = artistViewModel.artistName
    }
}
```